# XY inherits from both X and Y. casting XY* to X* then to Y* then calling Y's function results in calling X's function

Tags: c++, casting, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    virtual void x() = 0;
};

struct Y
{
    virtual void y() = 0;
};

struct XY : X, Y
{
    void x() override { std::cout << "X\n"; }
    void y() override { std::cout << "Y\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    XY xy;

    X* xptr = &xy;

    Y* yptr = (Y*)xptr;

    yptr->y(); //prints "X"....

    ((Y*)((X*)(&xy)))->y(); // prints "Y"....
}
```

Output:

```
X
Y
```

Can someone explain in some detail why this is happening? Why the first call is printing `X` and also why the two calls are different from each other?

Comment: `Y* yptr = (Y*)xptr;`  This cast here is effectively doing a `reinterprest_cast`, which just forces the cast.  It's not legal, nor safe.  In fact it's undefined behavior.  You can cast `xy` implicitly to `yptr` safely.

Comment: Looks like undefined bahviour to me. You're casting between unrelated types. It might work if you used dynamic_cast?

Comment: after `reinterpret_cast` you are still calling a pointer to `X`, therefore it calls `X`'s function. Nothing surprising even tho it is UB

Comment: @user, no this is not correct. It's interpreting X's vtable as if it was a Y vtable. It just happens that they are "compatible" because they have the same number of functions with the same signatures.

Comment: This illustrates why you should never C-style-cast to a pointer or reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, as far as the language is concerned, this is Undefined Behavior.

However, the actual chosen behavior does reveal how the innards of a typical C++ compiler works, so it can still be interesting to investigate why you got the output you did. That being said, It's important to remember that the following explanation is not universal. There are no hard requirement for things to work this way, and any code relying on things behaving like that is effectively broken, **even if it works on all compilers you try it on**.

C++ polymorphism is typically implemented using a vtable, which is basically a list of function pointers, and can be seen as a hidden member pointer in the object.

so

```
struct X
{
    virtual void x() = 0;
};

struct Y {
    virtual void y() = 0;
};
```

Is roughly equivalent to (it doesn't actually use `std::function<>`, but this makes the pseudo code more legible):

```
struct X {
    struct vtable_t {
      std::function<void(void*)> first_virtual_function;
    };
    
    vtable_t* vtable;

    void x() {
      vtable->first_virtual_function(this);
    }
};

struct Y {
    struct vtable_t {
      std::function<void(void*)> first_virtual_function;
    };
    
    vtable_t* vtable;

    void y() {
      vtable->first_virtual_function(this);
    }
};
```

Notice how `X::vtable_t` and `Y::vtable_t` are **coincidentally** essentially the same thing. If `X` and `Y` had different virtual functions, things would not line up this neatly.

Another important piece of the puzzle is that multiple inheritance is effectively a concatenation:

```
struct XY : X, Y {
    void x() override { std::cout << "X\n"; }
    void y() override { std::cout << "Y\n"; }
};

// is roughly equivalent to:
struct XY {
  static X::vtable vtable_for_x; // with first_virtual_function assigned to XY::x()
  static Y::vtable vtable_for_y; // with first_virtual_function assigned to XY::y()

  X x_base;
  Y y_base;

  XY() {
    x_base.v_table = &vtable_for_x;
    y_base.v_table = &vtable_for_y;
  }

  void x() { std::cout << "X\n"; }
  void y() { std::cout << "Y\n"; }
};
```

Which implies that casting from a multiple-inherited type to a base is not just a matter of changing the type of the pointer, the **value** has to change as well.

Only the `X` pointer is equivalent to the base object pointer, the `Y` pointer is actually a **different address**.

```
X* xptr = &xy;  
// is equivalent to
X* xptr = &xy->x_base;

Y* xptr = &xy;  
// is equivalent to
Y* xptr = &xy->y_base;
```

Finally, when you cast from `X` to `Y`, since these types are unrelated, the operation is a `reinterpret_cast`, so while the pointer might be a pointer to `Y`, the underlying object is still an `X`.

Luckily for you, things line up:

- Both X and Y have the vtable pointer as the first member object.
- Both X and Y's vtable are effectively equivalent, the former pointing to `XY::x()`, the later to `XY::y()`.

So when the logic of invoking `y()` is applied to an object of type `X`, the bits just happen to line up to invoke `XY::x()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`Y* yptr = (Y*)xptr;` does a `reinterpret_cast`

From [Explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) `( new_type ) expression`:

> When the C-style cast expression is encountered, the compiler attempts to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this order:
>
> a) `const_cast<new_type>(expression);`
> b) `static_cast<new_type>(expression)`, with extensions: pointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to member to pointer to member of unambiguous non-virtual base;
> c) `static_cast` (with extensions) followed by `const_cast;`
> d) `reinterpret_cast<new_type>(expression);`
> e) `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`.
>
> The first choice that satisfies the requirements of the respective cast operator is selected, even if it cannot be compiled

**a**, **b** and **c** will not work so it lands on **d**.
The correct cast, `dynamic_cast`, isn't even considered when you do C-style casting, so you still have a pointer to the  `X` part of an `XY` that you dereference through the eyes of a `Y` when you do `yptr->y()`. This makes your program have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Never use C-style casting. It's better to be explicit so that you know that you get the correct cast:

```
Y* yptr = dynamic_cast<Y*>(xptr);
```